# Infer dependant parameter type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics

There is a generic type for messages:

```
type Message = Message1 | Message2 | ...;
```

Each specific message type contains field called `type`, e.g.:

```
type Message1 = {
  type: 'message-1',
  payload1: string;
}

type Message2 = {
  type: 'message-2',
  payload2: number;
}
```

The `subscribe` function should accept two parameters: `messageType` and `onMessage`:

```
function subscribe(messageType: Message['type'], onMessage: (message: ???) => void): void {
   ...
}
```

The question is how to define second parameter of `subscribe` function so that the `onMessage` callback can infer type of the message. For instance,

```
subscribe('message-1', (msg) => { /* msg should be of type Message1 */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this with the descriptor in the model itself you can make a generic switch to infer the correct model.

```js
type Message = MessageOne | MessageTwo;

type MessageOne = {
    type: 'message-1',
    payload1: string;
}

type MessageTwo = {
    type: 'message-2',
    payload2: number;
}

type GenericMessage<T extends Message['type']> =
    T extends 'message-1' ? MessageOne :
    T extends 'message-2' ? MessageTwo :
    never;

function subscribe<Type extends Message['type']>(messageType: Type, onMessage: (message: GenericMessage<Type>) => void): void {
    throw new Error('function "subscribe" is not implemented');
}

subscribe('message-1', (message) => { 
    console.log(message.payload1);
});

subscribe('message-2', (message) => { 
    console.log(message.payload2);
});
```

You can look at it in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAshDO8CGBzaBeWDloPIDtoAfLRVCAFQHcB7AbgCgHRJScICMoBvBqfqCwgAuKAHIAttnIBaAIxiANHwFgkIADY0kAEzmj4wAE4BLfCkYBfJkLblqNKJl4DB4EeKlk0MgExKVfjVNbR1fUXwAVwkAIwgjKxt3KABxCEJTAGM4bwgAHgooCAAPYHSdeDs0AG0xITEAXQA+J0CoQpKy-ArPaR8FKAB+Ko5CKGE2jtLyysk+iD8xIZGHcbbCADd4xgYAM0j8TOATGnwoeEiY+EzTOILkzpmR2vrmgAovdgp3UW-IRSgpxy7FEH3mojSGRM2Xm90gTQAlE4WhsaCYdAjRKj0Tw2sAABZGGhUKCEEkAUSMRKMbzE+0Ox1OUAARBcrjcTHFmVATJV8DRgDyJGANBApPgyjoxAjEgw2ddbhBaZ9ZAoAWDckj0C1uFA2plTvAaKKAHRaFAa9gm4JaXRyGUMSwOuWXBWcpVzXKLdUqtBanV61wG-BG03my3ka3qW1hB1OuhAA).

Comment: Thank you! I wonder if there is a way not to add this additional type. This solution works but it violates the concept of single source of truth.